# Trello write permission via OAuth

Tags: c++, qt, oauth, trello

I'm using KQOAuthManager to get trello authorization. But it gives me only read permissions how to get write permissions too. I going after every step and using this three links:

```
trello.com/1/OAuthGetRequestToken
trello.com/1/OAuthAuthorizeToken
trello.com/1/OAuthGetAccessToken
```

But if I add to any some params after ? it don't affect on code. This is code which I'm running: http://pastebin.com/nDJuuJFR

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found way, just changed link in oauthManager->getUserAuthorization(link) to https://trello.com/1/authorize?scope=read,write from https://Trello.com/1/OAuthAuthorizeToken